# Lollipop Bad WiFi connection and Fallback to Mobile Network, how to to switch to WiFi?

Tags: android, wifi, android-5.0-lollipop, connectivity

Tom,
I have similar problem that you have but can't solve it the way how you and other guys recommend. My onAvailable callback never hit for WiFi that is not Internet connected. Here is my code
    @TargetApi(21)
    public static void connectToWifiNetworkSynchronousApi21(final WifiConfiguration wifiConfig) {
        NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();

```
    builder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
    builder.removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);

    builder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiConfig.SSID);
    NetworkRequest request = builder.build();

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)App.getApp().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    cm.requestNetwork(request,new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onAvailable(Network network) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LOG.debug("onAvailable:{} requested {}", network.toString(), wifiConfig.networkId);
            super.onAvailable(network);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLosing(Network network, int maxMsToLive) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Network network) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onLost(network);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCapabilitiesChanged(Network network,
                NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLinkPropertiesChanged(Network network,
                LinkProperties linkProperties) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onLinkPropertiesChanged(network, linkProperties);
        }

    }); 
}
```

Comment: Who is Tom? Did you forget to attach the link to another question?